# Center the text in a row of an HTML table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the text in the last column of the `table` so that it is aligned with the text in the previous columns. Though, I have no idea how to do this. I've tried putting it in `<p>` tags, I've tried moving the `<IMG>` around, nothing seems to work. Any ideas? **See "Week 3" for the row that I am working on.**

NOTE: The table isn't complete, we won't be playing the Packers every week of the season! :P

[image]

CSS:

```
<table class="luncheon">
        <caption><h2 class="luncheon">2015 Whitewater Warrior Schedule</h2></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Week</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Home/Away</th>
                <th>Win/Loss</th>
                <th>Game Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">1</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">2</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1"><b>3</b></td>
                <td><b>SEPTEMBER 13</b></td>
                <td><b>HOME</b></td>
                <td><b>WIN</b></td>
                <td><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"><b>&nbsp; PACKERS: 10 &nbsp; WARRIORS: 23</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">4</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">5</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">6</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">7</td>
                <td>BYE</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="right">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">8</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">9</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">10</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">11</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">12</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">13</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">14</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">15</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">16</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border_bottom">
                <td rowspan="1">17</td>
                <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>WIN</td>
                <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" class="center">Post-Season Games are TBD</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: use vertical-align css for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images by default align with the text along the baseline. Keeping your current code structure, you can use `vertical-align: middle` for your image as follows:

```
<td class="right">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"> &nbsp; 
    <span style="vertical-align: middle">Packers: 10 &nbsp; Warriors: 23</span>
</td>
```

Though I'd eventually get rid of the `nbsp;` and use css with margin or padding instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `vertical-align:middle` to the cell's image should fix the problem.

```
.luncheon td img {
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you refactor the code so that warriors has it's own TD cell? This will ensure that the team names line up!

```
<table class="luncheon">
    <caption><h2 class="luncheon">2015 Whitewater Warrior Schedule</h2></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Home/Away</th>
            <th>Win/Loss</th>
            <th colspan="2">Game Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
            <td rowspan="1">1</td>
            <td>SEPTEMBER 13</td>
            <td>HOME</td>
            <td>WIN</td>
            <td class="right"><img src="images/packers.png" alt="Town Hall logo"><span>Packers: 10</span></td>
            <td>Warriors: 23</td>
        </tr>
        // etc etc
```

CSS

```
 // vertically align regardless of parent height
 td{ position: relative; )
 td span{ position: absolute; top: 50%; translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `images/packers.png` and text after it aligned by baseline. I think you need to make two blocks with equal height: i.e. encapsulate text in `span` in apply next css:

```
.luncheon .right span {
    whitespace: no-wrap;
    display: inline-block;
    height: {height-of-your-packers-image};
}
```

UPD: Variant 2: Set image to background (middle,center) and padding for text:

```
.luncheon .right {
    background-image: url("{path-to-image}/images/packers.png");
    background-position: left middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: {width-of-your-packers-image};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want whole  content to align right, create class for that  and use { text-align: right; } for that class;

If you want that  to be left align, i ll provide you alternate but its not best solution, create another  for that game image.for text part use another  with { text-align: right; }